# Best practices to avoid Python float rounding errors?

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, rounding

So I encountered my first noticeable issue with float representation in Python.

The error came from multiplying the float:2.55 by the float:100.  The error being I expect 255.0, but python returns 254.99999999999997. I get the same problem when 100 is an integer.

I noticed there are a lot of questions about similar topics on this issue on SO. Along with the documentation for floating-point arithmetic[Python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) and this great article on how it works over all languages [David Goldberg](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). However, I am still wondering about the best practices here.

Using round() seemed to fix the issue, but I noticed from other posts that this has its own issues with certain float values. So what should I do in cases like this to avoid error?

Comment: For the most part, you should not use floating-point arithmetic if you want to “avoid error.” Floating-point arithmetic is **designed** to **approximate** real arithmetic. That is its intent: To serve for people who want to do physics simulations or similar things where approximations are okay. It can be used for exact mathematics in some situations, but that generally requires some expertise and should not be a student’s first use of floating-point.

Comment: In part because of that design, there is no single best practice for using floating-point arithmetic for things it was not designed to do. Using “round” potentially results in more error, not less. What solution is appropriate for a particular problem depends on the particular problem.

Comment: Print with more precision to see its true value as a `float`.   The product is not an _error_.  The assumption that the initial value in the `float` was exactly 2.55 is an error.